# how to detect monotonically increasing gauge over period of time?

Tags: prometheus, alert, grafana, gauge

For a gauge meter scraped by Prometheus, say a temperature, is there a way how to detect it has been monotonically increasing for given period of time, say last couple of minutes or hours. This is so that it can be alerted on in Grafana.

This would be handy to detect that AC went off and such.

Comment: The deriv() of the gauge will be positive if temperature is increasing and negative when starts to get down. Does it help?

Comment: Given that `deriv()` accepts a time range, it seems like this could do the trick.